# Atualizar Conexão Ocomon para PHP7

Tags: php, mysql

Apos atualizar a versão do php da 5 para o 7 o sistema não abre, a função mysql_connect foi descontinuada tentei utilizar mysqli e não consegui fazer funcionar.

**Erro:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/grupo501/public_html/suporte/includes/classes/conecta.class.php:53 Stack trace: #0 /home/grupo501/public_html/suporte/index.php(44): conexao->conecta('MYSQL') #1 {main} thrown in /home/grupo501/public_html/suporte/includes/classes/conecta.class.php on line 53

class.conecta.php

```
 function conecta($BANCO){
        if (strtoupper($BANCO) =='MYSQL') {

        $this->con=mysql_connect(SQL_SERVER,SQL_USER,SQL_PASSWD)or die(mysql_error());
        $this->db=mysql_select_db(SQL_DB,$this->con);
            if ($this->con == 0){
                $retorno = "ERRO DE CONEXÃO - SERVIDOR!<br>";
            }
            else if ($this->db == 0){
                $retorno = "ERRO DE CONEXÃO - BANCO DE DADOS!<br>";
            } else {
                $retorno = "";
            }

            return  $retorno;

        }

    }

    function desconecta($BANCO){
            mysql_close($this->con);
    }
```

Depois tentativa de atualização

```
function conecta($BANCO){
    if (strtoupper($BANCO) =='MYSQL') {

    $this->con=mysqli_connect(SQL_SERVER,SQL_USER,SQL_PASSWD)or die(mysql_error());
    $this->db=mysqli_select_db(SQL_DB,$this->con);

        if ($this->con == 0){
            $retorno = "ERRO DE CONEXÃO - SERVIDOR!<br>";
        }
        else if ($this->db == 0){
            $retorno = "ERRO DE CONEXÃO - BANCO DE DADOS!<br>";
        } else {
            $retorno = "";
        }

        return  $retorno;

    }

}

function desconecta($BANCO){
        mysql_close($this->con);
}

**Erro:**
```

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/grupo501/public_html/suporte/includes/classes/conecta.class.php on line 54

Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /home/grupo501/public_html/suporte/includes/classes/conecta.class.php on line 55

Notice: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to int in /home/grupo501/public_html/suporte/includes/classes/conecta.class.php on line 56

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /home/grupo501/public_html/suporte/index.php:51 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/grupo501/public_html/suporte/index.php on line 51

Comment: Seria interessante se você especificasse a sua pergunta, nesse formato aí só tem um erro e vários códigos.

Comment: bom dia, desculpe, apos atualizar a versão do php da 5 para o 7 o sistema não abre mais a função mysql_connect foi descontinuada tentei utilizar mysqli e não consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: @Vagner ao utilizar o mysqli (mais recente), você teve outro erro ou foi o mesmo erro?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com a tentativa de atualização.